# Recursively traverse object in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, recursion

I'm converting diverse JSON objects to structured objects and want to iterate over all the nodes to process each one hierarchically. JSON framework supports conversion to an NSDictionary, which I thought was unstructured. I want to recursively iterate through each item and pay respect to the structure. How would this be done with either a dictionary or generic NSOBject?

Example:

```
- (void) processParsedObject:(NSDictionary *)obj
{
    if (atTheEndOfTheTail) {
        NSLog(@"Object description: %@\n\n", obj.description);

    }
    for (id object in obj) {
        [self processParsedObject:object];
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I asked the question more clearly here (with answer):

[Recursively traverse NSDictionary of unknown structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186170/recursively-traverse-nsdictionary-of-unknown-structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate all the keys in an NSDictionary using:

```
NSEnumerator* keyEnum = [myDictionary keyEnumerator];
NSObject* nextKey;
while ((nextKey = [keyEnum nextObject]) != nil)
{
    NSObject* nextValue = [myDictionary objectForKey:nextKey];
    //... do something with the object and/or key ...
}
```

Comment: Or just use fast enumeration (`for...in`)

Comment: Good point. You can also do the above recursively to get sub-objects, and sub-sub-object, etc.

Comment: That's what I figured, too. Could you show me some example syntax? I was butchering it in my example.

Comment: The docs for fast enumeration are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html). It would be something like: `NSObject* nextKey;for (nextKey in myDictionary) { NSObject* nextValue = [myDictionary objectForKey:nextKey];}`