# How to search for a specific value in a long plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

I got a p list with

```
root - array
  Item 0 - dictionary
    locationName - string
    rating - number
    reason - string
  Item 1
  ....
```

So i got a NSString with the input text and i want to search through my plist to check if the inputText is exist in my plist.

All i need to check in plist is locationName.

I tried to take my plist into a `NSDictionary` but i didn't know how to do continue

Do i need a loop like this

```
for(int k=0;k<= plist.length;k++;)
```

or is there any other way to go?

Comment: Please format the question content so it's readable. Why are you using a plist?

Comment: Some of these answers might apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186170/recursively-traverse-nsdictionary-of-unknown-structure

Comment: What can i use instead of plist?I will add data later on.What is there that you cant read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSPredicate` with format of `SELF.locationName = 'some location'` on an array of the elements:

```
NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.locationName = %@", @"My Location"];
NSArray * filteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];

NSDictionary * firstElement = filteredArray[0];
```

Comment: that won't be useful for my purpose.

Comment: @judge I can't help you if you don't say why it's not useful. The code-snippet above does what you want. Finds a dictionary where key 'locationName' has given value.