# Get list of all leaves from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, tree, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary that contains more dictionaries. The final dictionary's value (leaf) is an array containing some data. The depth to each leaf is unknown.

I attempted to write recursive function to combine all the arrays that are children of the level 0 key.

Here's what I have so far:

```
- (NSArray *)getAllDictArrays:(NSDictionary *)dictionary WithKey:(NSString *)key
{

    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        // grab array and save for later or append to global array and return later
    } else {
        NSDictionary *newDict = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
        NSString *newKey;
        for (newKey in newDict.allKeys) {
            //NSLog(@"Calling Key: %@", newKey);
            [self getAllDictArrays:newDict WithKey:newKey];
        }
    }


    return ???;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Could you give me any help with my function? I don't really know how to specific.

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186170/recursively-traverse-nsdictionary-of-unknown-structure