# How to recursively traverse NSDictionary in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, nsdictionary

I am writing an app, and one of the features I need to implement requires the app to pull JSON data from a website, store it in a dictionary, then be able to use all of the keys and display the values. I will not know what the structure of the dictionary will look like, so I was hoping to recursively traverse the dictionary to retrieve all of the information.

I have the the JSON stored in a dictionary from the website that I need, and when I put the dictionary variable in a println() statement it displays correctly.

[I found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186170/recursively-traverse-nsdictionary-of-unknown-structure) and I think this, or some variation of this should work, but I am still fairly new to swift and I am not sure how this translates from Objective-c to swift.

The part of that link that I am interested in is this:

```
(void)enumerateJSONToFindKeys:(id)object forKeyNamed:(NSString     *)keyName
{
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    // If it's a dictionary, enumerate it and pass in each key value to check
    [object enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
        [self enumerateJSONToFindKeys:value forKeyNamed:key];
    }];
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    // If it's an array, pass in the objects of the array to check
    [object enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [self enumerateJSONToFindKeys:obj forKeyNamed:nil];
    }];
}
else
{
    // If we got here (i.e. it's not a dictionary or array) so its a key/value that we needed 
    NSLog(@"We found key %@ with value %@", keyName, object);
}
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about this, any help or pointers in the right direction are appreciate. Thanks!

EDIT: This is the direction I started to go in, but there were a lot of errors. I tried to fix them but didn't have much luck.

```
func enumerateJSONToFindKeys(id:AnyObject, keyName:NSString){

    if id.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)
    {
        AnyObject.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock(id.key, id.value, stop:Bool())
            {
                self.enumerateJSONToFindKeys(id.value, forKeyNamed: keyName)
        }
    }
    else if id.isKindOfClass(NSArray)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
func enumerateJSONToFindKeys(object:AnyObject, forKeyNamed named:String?) {
    if let dict = object as? NSDictionary {
        for (key, value) in dict {
            enumerateJSONToFindKeys(value, forKeyNamed: key as? String)
        }
    }
    else if let array = object as? NSArray {
        for value in array {
            enumerateJSONToFindKeys(value, forKeyNamed: nil)
        }
    }
    else {
        println("found key \(named) value \(object)")
    }
}
```

It uses the Swift `as?` conditional casting operator as well as native iteration over both the NSDictionary and NSArray.